# Accessibility issue when presenting UIViewController with style overCurrentContext

Tags: ios, accessibility, presentviewcontroller, uiaccessibility

When I present UIViewController with style overCurrentContext. Voice Over is reading content from previous view controller when swipe right after reaching the last element of current ViewController.

It's working fine for iOS 13 and above. Problem is with iOS 12.*.

Comment: Did you try setting `definesPresentationContext = true` ? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/overcurrentcontext

Comment: Yes I did try..But not working.

Comment: You can share related part of your code